# How would having a codeword withweight two affect the coset priority here?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I am trying to understand syndrome decoding. My understanding so far is that we calculate syndrome vector based on what we assume would be the error and that the coset leader vector chosen is to be the one with minimal weight.
I don't understand this comment how would having a codeword of weight 2 result in not choosing weight 1 vector as thecoset leader ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiw5h.jpg

Comment: A codeword $x$ of weight two is the sum of two vectors (neither a codeword) of weight one: $x=y_1+y_2$. In this case $y_1$ and $y_2$ belong to the same coset (assuming binary). Which one will you call the coset leader with nothing to base a decision on?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment

Comment: Wouldn't that mean by extension in case of weight of 4, x = y1 + y2 + y3 + y4

Comment: I tried changing row 2 to have a weight of 2 and check the cosets. If we change it to 01001000 and check the cosets we get (and please correct me if I am wrong) the two cosets that result in the syndrome vector of 0100 are 010000000 and 00111000 so weights 1 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition coset and coset leader.** A coset is a set parametrized by the its syndrome $s\in\mathbb{F}^{n-k}$ and designates a set of vectors with the same syndrome, i.e.
$$ A(s) = \{ x \in \mathbb{F}^n : xH^{\mathrm{T}}=s \}. $$
The coset leader of a coset $A(s)$ is the vector with minimum weight in $A(s)$.

By the definition of the coset it is easy to see that for all $x_1,x_2 \in A(s)$, it holds that for any two $x_1-x_2\in \mathcal{C}$ and thus $d(x_1,x_2)\geq d_{min}(\mathcal{C})$. Hence, if the coset leader has  weight 1, $\mathrm{wt}(x_1)=1$, this coset leader is unique provided that $d_{min}(\mathcal{C})\geq 3$.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you recommend a book or a course for a beginner. My abstract and linear algebra are a bit weary so if you know of resources that take the extra step to explain in a little more details I would apperreciate it if you let mention it.

Comment: @mar In my experience most books about coding theory cover a reasonable amount of algebra. One book that I can recommend is J. Justesen and T. Høholdt, "A Course in Error-Correcting Codes", 2004